# Transfer a file from Server A to B, using your PC as terminal then turning off your PC?

Tags: windows-7, linux, download, putty, wget

I need to copy `server-a.com/file.zip` to `server-b.com`. Let's assume the file is really big.

Using my home PC, I SSH to `server-b.com` and type `wget server-a.com/file.zip`

How do you do it so that the download will continue even if I close my SSH terminal and PC? Note: I close my PC because the download will take several hours.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. I'll delete my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use GNU Screen for this. You can read more about what it is on its website (http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) - but one of the things I love about it is that you can detach it and leave your shell running merrily without interference.

Then, later, you can log back in and pass
    Screen -r
And get right back to where you were.

Screen also has a lot of other beneficial features, and it's a program I'd recommend anyone using the terminal a lot should use.

Comment: Good, I'm glad. Keep it in your *NIX toolbox for next time - it's a real productivity booster.